# Linux command not working from PHP website but working from terminal

Tags: php, linux, phantomjs, cpanel

I am using phantomjs and its working when I test from CWP terminal.
I install it in `usr/local/share/phantomjs` also set environment variable

I run a common From Terminal from different directories to make sure its working: `phantomjs --version` // response 2.1.1

When i register new domain and create new user Cpanel account. From PHP i make sure exec function is properly working, but when i enter command `phantomjs --version`
or 
`phantomjs exmple.js` it return empty response.

Code:

```
exec("phantomjs --version",$output, $code); // $output = empty. $code = 127
exec("phantomjs example.js",$output, $code); // $output = empty. $code = 127
exec("ls",$output, $code); // (to test if exec working or not) it return files list, and its wroking
```

How can i allow cpanel user to access phantomjs from PHP exec?

**Server**

```
Centos 7
PHP 7.2
Cpanel User: dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try direct path of the executable. Run

```
whereis phantomjs
```

to get the path and pass that to `exec`.

Comment: Yes it work, 
But i already add path in envoirment, and its work directly from terminal. What i need to do so i can use just phantomjs?

Comment: Here is tutorial that i follow, https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-phantomjs-on-centos-7/ and Its command for environment variable ln -sf /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin